# how to get the event of app instance clearing in android

Tags: android, instance

in my app I am using push notifications to notify the user about something.Based on different app state I have to assign different activities to click event of notification. If the user press home button and app is in background i have to handle that scenario as well. But here the issue come when user clear the app instance from memory. If user do that I have to consider it as app closed. But i dont know how to get that app instance clear event. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The task you are willing to solve is equivalent to protection against the task manager. I am not sure that your app knows better than the user whether or not to show the ads. Please do not create malware.

Try the UncaughtExceptionHandler stuff like [setUncaughtExceptionHandler()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setUncaughtExceptionHandler(java.lang.Thread.UncaughtExceptionHandler)). I am *not* sure it will be necessarily called, and it may depend on the Android version, but it is something to start with.

Another possibility is to use one or more remote service(s). The processes will not die all at once, there's a good chance that one process may notice the death of another process. There *should* be some kind of wait-for-process-to-complete at least on the JNI level.

One more possibility is to use two applications, one monitoring the other...

After you solve this problem, please post your own answer telling the world what you did.